# Is there a way to print the sql that would be executed on pdo->commit?

Tags: php, pdo

I've got a script that is capable of building up a longish transaction of prepared statements, and I'd like a way to print what is about to be executed.

None of the [class methods](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) in PDO look promising.

**EDIT:**
This is for a (hacky) db upgrade script, as a sanity check. Devs are supposed to append to the script as they modify the database.

```
$commonStmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT ... VALUES (:a, :b)");
function commonInsert($a, $b) {
    global $commonStmt;
    $commonStmt->bindParam(':a', $a);
    $commonStmt->bindParam(':b', $b);
    $commonStmt->execute();
}


$pdo->beginTransaction();
if ($db_version < $file_version) {
    commonInsert('a', 'b');
}
if ($db_version < $file_version) {
    commonInsert('c', 'd');
}

if ($db_version < $file_version) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT ...');
    $stmt->execute();
}

if ($db_version < $file_version) {
    $pdo->query('INSERT');
}

// this will only get longer

$pdo->commit();
```

I could add debug statements (per Tamas' suggestion) to *each* update, but that seems onerous for a simple sanity check. And the `commonInsert` case is the one least likely to need it.

Comment: If the database driver supports prepared statements, then there's not much to print. PDO does not cobble together an old-fashioned SQL statement, it sends the query and the bound data to the database in two separate steps. Does this help/answer/obsolete your question?

Comment: If the fact that it does it in separate steps means that it doesn't keep enough metainformation around to do what I want, then yes. Although since this is for a sanity check (and not to generate well-formed sql) I would be willing to deal with something like the output of PDOStatement::debugDumpParams, but for an entire transaction.

Comment: PDO is just a layer, it doesn't "keep track" what's executed between a  beginTransaction and a commit. It's happening on the database level, so if you want debug output, you need to do it on every execution on the PHP level.

Comment: Tamas, thanks. That makes sense, if it is a little unfortunate for introspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about [PDOStatement::debugDumpParams](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php)?

Comment: This is close to what I want, but unfortunately since it operates at the statement level it won't really work for my case. I've updated my question to show why.

Comment: On second thought, since this is mostly for debugging and things that are in the repo should be safe, I can just tell devs "insert your own debug statements."